# Python-Aiohttp/Asyncio API request returning ContentTypeError - JSON with unexpected mimetype, but not always

Tags: python, json, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am attempting to make an API request, pull down specific chunks of the response and ultimately save it into a file for later processing. I also first want to mention that the script works full, until I begin to pull larger sets of data.
When I open the params to a larger date range, I receive:
ContentTypeError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ContentTypeError: 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: text/html'

```
async def get_dataset(session, url):
async with session.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=params) as resp:
    dataset = await resp.json()
    return dataset['time_entries']


async def main():
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for page in range(1, total_pages):
            url = "https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/time_entries?page=" + str(page)
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_dataset(session, url)))

        dataset = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

If I keep my params small enough, then it works without issue. But too large of a date range and the error pops up, and anything past the snippet I shared above does not run
More for reference:

```
url_address = "https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/time_entries/"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": 'application/json',
    "Authorization": authToken,
    "Harvest-Account-ID": accountID
}
params = {
    "from": StartDate,
    "to": EndDate
}
```

Any ideas on what would cause this to work on certain data sizes but fail on larger sets? I am assuming the JSON is becoming malformed at some point, but I am unsure of how to examine that and/or prevent it from happening, since I am able to pull multiple pages from the API and successfully appending on the smaller data pulls.

Comment: I was using`data={json_body}` in my `async with session.post(url, data={json_body} )` and I received the same error and imo the error thrown by the lib is a bit vague. 
Then I changed & renamed param to `json={json_body}` and the error got resolved

Comment: Although its not a technically correct solution but can you try by updating your code to use `async with session.get(url=url, headers=headers, json=params) as resp:` and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP: Thank you to the others who gave answers. I discovered the issue and implemented a solution. A friend pointed out that aiohttp can return that error message if the response is of an error page instead of the expected json content i.e. a html page giving a 429 HTTP too many requests. I looked up the API limits and found they do have it set to 100 requests per 15 seconds.

My solution was to implement the `asyncio-throttle` module which allowed me to directly limit the requests and time period. You can find this on the devs [GitHub](https://github.com/hallazzang/asyncio-throttle)

Here is my updated code with the implementation, very simple! For my instance I needed to limit my requests to 100 per 15 seconds which you can see below as well.

```
async def get_dataset(session, url, throttler):
    while True:
        async with throttler:
            async with session.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=params) as resp:
                dataset = await resp.json()
                return dataset['time_entries']


async def main():
    tasks = []
    throttler = Throttler(rate_limit=100, period=15)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        try:
            for page in range(1, total_pages):
                url = "https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/time_entries?page=" + str(page)
                tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_dataset(session, url, throttler)))

            dataset = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```